# Session issue with AJAX call (Symfony 4)

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony4

I'm currently coding a chat.
This is the issue I'm facing with Symfony 4:
When I search if there's a new connected user with `setTimeout()` from Jquery/AJAX to controller, the session "crashes" (error 500 and I loose user connexion).

I already changed php.ini, raising `gc.maxlifetime` to 43200 and I changed config/package/framework.yaml like needed, but nothing works.

That's what I modified in config/package/framework.yaml:

```
session:
    handler_id: ~
    cookie_secure: auto
    cookie_samesite: lax
    gc_maxlifetime: 43200
    cookie_lifetime: 43200
    cookie_httponly: false
```

Then I even tried to set `always_remember_me` to `true` in config/package/security.yaml:

```
remember_me: 
    secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
    lifetime: 43200
    path:     /
    always_remember_me: true
```

This is Jquery/AJAX part :

```
function userActif()
{
    var nbUserActif = $('#listeUserActif');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'chat/userActif',
        success: function (data) {
        if(data != nbUserActif.attr('data-nbuseractif') && date > 0){
            $('#listeUserActif').attr('data-nbuseractif', data);
            $('#listeUserActif').load('chat/listUser');
            setTimeout('userActif();', 2000);
        }
        else {parent.location.href = '/';}
        },
        error: function() {parent.location.href = '/';}
    });
}
```

I'd like the session to keep going during the time specified in the AJAX call.
Do you have any solutions ? Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow ne parle pas français.

Comment: @deceze can you review the edit ?

Comment: @Jules Thanks for your effort, but: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/476

Comment: @deceze alright did not know about it, thanks